# Qt creator - The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2 default project

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I installed QT Creator 4.0 on OS X 10.11, when I try to build any project template I get the following: [Error output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ9Gk.png).
Any idea what causes this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Let's see some code.....

Comment: Doesn't matter, not a single example project or empty template builds always the same output (Just downloaded and installed Qt-Creator for OS X, didn't change any configuration)

Comment: Then I can be more more help than the error telling you that there is a problem with an unexpected EOF. Sorry, but I have no ideas. Did you install the required XCode stuff to run QT projects?

Comment: I have Xcode 7 (and command line tools) installed and selected, also with no configuration changes